# Arquillian org.junit.runner.Runner NoClassDefFoundError when JMockit on classpath

Tags: java, jboss-arquillian, jmockit

I am attempting to do a really simple Arquillian test against a remote Weblogic 12.1.x so for example I have the following

```
public class MyBean {

}
```

And then the test

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class InjectionTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "lib.jar")
            .addClass(MyBean.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml")
     }

    @Inject
    MyBean bean;

    @Test
    public void test_bean_not_null() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(bean);
    }

}
```

Simple enough! However I get the following stack trace

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.junit.runner.Runner
                at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:61)
                at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
                at org.junit.internal.requests.FilterRequest.getRunner(FilterRequest.java:36)
                at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
                at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.container.JUnitTestRunner.execute(JUnitTestRunner.java:66)
                at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:170)
                at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:135)
                at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:98)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:32)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3683)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3649)
                at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
                at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2433)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2281)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2259)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1691)
                at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1651)
                at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:270)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:348)
                at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:333)
                at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:54)
                at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
                at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:640)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:406)
                at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:346)
```

And here is the relevant section of my pom, I'm not sure what's wrong with it

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.13.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
        <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
        <version>1.18</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-persistence-dbunit</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.protocol</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-protocol-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.11.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-12.1.x</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT: If I remove JMockit from the dependencies list, it works! I do however need JMockit for my unit tests.**

Comment: You might need to use a newer version of JMockit than 1.18 - some work was done not long ago for custom class loading support in JMockit (tested with Arquillian on JBoss Wildfly 10.0). Out of curiosity, though, what do you need Arquillian for that JMockit itself can't do with `@Tested(fullyInitialized=true)`? I used this in the past to integration-test a Java EE 7 web app which used JPA + JSF + EJB.

Comment: I did try with 1.33 using the above dependency order and had the same issue. At the moment I'm just experimenting.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so apparently the order of the test dependencies matters, we need the arquillian junit container and junit itself BEFORE JMockit

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
    <version>1.18</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Does it mean that jmockit has its own, older version of JUnitas transitive dependency? What `mvn dependency:tree` says for both variants?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using embedded container or managed/remote one? Notice that if you are using managed or remote you need to add the library in deployment jar